# How to solve second order ODE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u: \mathbb R^{d} \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be  a function, and $f, g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz Space).

We consider, the following initial value problem (IVP):

$ (\frac{\partial ^2}{ \partial t^{2}} u(x,t) + 4\pi ^2 |x|^2 ) u(x,t)=0, u(x,0)= f(x),  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,0)= g(x).$

> My Question is: How to solve the above IVP?

Background: I know the solution  to this  is $u(x,t)=  [\cos (2 \pi t |x|)] f(x) + \frac{\sin t (2\pi t |x|)}{2\pi |x|} g(x).$  But I do not know by which method  one can reach to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a degenerate partial differential equation, in the sense that the derivative of $u$ is taken in only *one* variable. Therefore, the equation is equivalent to an ODE (in $t$), with $x$ being an auxiliary variable, or external parameter. I think you'll have no problem solving the ODE.